# How to play a video in a alert using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, video, alert

I'm trying to play a video in a alert dialog using JavaFX. The problem is that I can't find how to display the video or more how to insert it in the alert ?

Here is my alert code

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer( new Media(getClass().getResource("video.mp4").toExternalForm()));
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

private void alert(){
 Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
 alert.setTitle("Don't be a fool");
 alert.setHeaderText("");
 alert.setContentText("Do you really think your time is correct ?");
 Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`Alert`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) extends from [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), which means you can customize its [`DialogPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html). If you want to add a video to your alert, the best place is probably the dialog pane's `content`. But note that setting the `content` will replace the `contentText` (which you set in your example code):

> In addition to the header and content properties, there exists header text and content text properties. The way the *Text properties work is that they are a lower precedence compared to the Node properties, but they are far more convenient for developers in the common case, as it is likely the case that a developer more often than not simply wants to set a string value into the header or content areas of the DialogPane.

This means, if you still want to display `"Do you really think your time is correct?"`, you'll have to add your own `Label` to the content as well. For example:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Don't be a fool");
alert.setHeaderText("");

Label label = new Label("Do you really think your time is correct?");
VBox content = new VBox(10, label, mediaView);
content.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);

alert.setOnShowing(e -> player.play());
alert.showAndWait();
```